# what is the motivation of Hamilton-DeTurck Ricci ﬂow?

Tags: differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations, riemannian-geometry, ricci-flow

Hamilton-DeTurck Ricci ﬂow : $\partial_{\lambda} g_{\mu \nu}=-2 R_{\mu \nu}+\nabla_{\mu} V_{\nu}+\nabla_{\nu} V_{\mu}$. i now have studied some paper , i think the main reason is that the original Ricci flow is not invariant under coordinate transformation. Here is the one explanation from a paper, which shows that the Hamilton-DeTurck Ricci ﬂow will generate a vector (V) along flow,which ensure that flow equation keeps invirant under any coordinate transformation . I wonder if it is the main reason why give rise up to Hamilton-DeTurck Ricci ﬂow ?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The Ricci flow equation IS invariant under coordinate transformation.

I think the main motivation is from PDE. Since the RF is degenerate parabolic, the existence and uniqueness are not immediate from "standard" PDE theory, even when restricted on compact manifolds.

This is why Hamilton made a huge effort (The Hard Implicit Function Theorem) in proving the existence of RF in [here](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.jdg/1214436922). He explained the degeneracy starting at p.260.

Shortly after this paper, Deturck gives [another method](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.jdg/1214509286) to prove the existence. In particular, the Detruck Ricci Flow is introduced. The Deturck Ricci Flow is strictly parabolic and differs from the Ricci Flow only by a family of diffeomorphisms. Note that his proof is essentially just 3 pages long.

The DeTurck Ricci Flow is essential in the non-compact situation. It is used both in proving the [existence](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.jdg/1214443292) and [uniqueness](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.jdg/1175266184).

The DeTurck trick is also generalized to other geometric flows like the Mean Curvature Flow.

Comment: but i have posted a picture above and it is said RF is not invariant under flow (see yellow highlights ), and in this paper author think RF can be modified by adding a a family of diffeomorphisms(DeTurck Ricci Flow) , which will be invariant under flow.how to think about the author's comments?

Comment: May I know what is (I,1)? @explorer

Comment: that is the original (Hamilton) Ricci flow $\frac{\partial g_{ab}}{\partial \lambda}=-2R_{ab}$

Comment: in yet ?@Arctic Char